# is it possible to refer to a type when implementing a function with type parameters in typescript

Tags: typescript, function, type-parameter

I want to split the type specification and the implementation of a function in typescript

For example:

If I have a type like this

```
type MyFuncType = () => void
```

I can create an implementation that is an instance of that type like this:

```
const myFuncImp: MyFuncType = () => {
    //implementation
}
```

I now want to do this with type parameters. My approach does not work:

```
type MyFuncType<T> = () => void

const myFuncImp: MyFuncType = () => {
    //implementation
}
```

this results in a error:

```
Generic type 'MyFuncType' requires 1 type argument(s)
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the generic parameter to the function type instead of the type alias:

```
type MyFuncType = <T>(a: string) => void;
// instead of: type MyFuncType<T> = () => void;

const myFuncImp: MyFuncType = <T>(a) => {
    //implementation
    const myArray: T[] = [];
    a.endsWith("foo")
};
```

Comment: That's the quickest solution I've ever gotten to a question. Brilliant

Comment: Follow up question: How can I then refer to the type parameter in the implementation? if I want to do: const myArray: T[] = []

Comment: Insert `<T>` before the function's parameter list.

Comment: I've tried that, but that triggers that the compiler forgets the type of the 'a' parameter. Can that be solved as well without respecifying the type?

Comment: I don't know why, but apparently you need to repeat the parameter types. Perhaps a TypeScript expert can chime in.